# binary tree pruning c++

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I was solving this question https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-pruning/description/ and came up with the solution directly below (which doesn't change the tree at all). When i debug this, it does enter the if statement - meaning it recognizes that a and b are both null for the leaf node, but when I assign root=nullptr it doesn't actually change the root (which is a leaf) to null. why doesn't my code work as it should?

```
TreeNode* pruneTree(TreeNode* root) {
 if (root == nullptr){return nullptr;}
        TreeNode *a = pruneTree(root->left);
        TreeNode *b = pruneTree(root->right);
        if (root->val == 0 && a==nullptr && b== nullptr){
                return nullptr; // or root = nullptr, they have same effect
}
        return root;
}
```

I am just confused on why it actually does change the value of the pointer to null when using the code below, when the only thing that is different is

```
root->left = pruneTree(root->left);
root->right = pruneTree(root->right);
```

the correct answer is:

```
    TreeNode* pruneTree(TreeNode* root) {
        if (root == nullptr){return nullptr;}
        root->left = pruneTree(root->left);
        root->right = pruneTree(root->right);
        if (root->val == 0 && root->left == nullptr && root->right == nullptr){
           return nullptr;
       
        }
        return root;
    }
```

my guess would be that this gives us direct access to not only the spot in memory for the left and right children, but also for the root itself? (which is why we are able to "delete" it?) not really delete but just return nullptr for it.

Comment: thanks for catching that. typo. please elaborate

Comment: The first version of the code can/will leave dangling pointers in the `left` and/or `right` members of the active node pointed to by `root` unless the potential modifications to those pointers are captured (either by return value as shown in the second example, or by reference arguments, which are not used in this code).

Comment: well the left and right pointers are there only to check if the children are null. no modifications need to be done. my confusion arises as to why the actual root cannot be changed to null via my code, when that is what is being passed into the function recursively

Comment: Ok. I see what you're saying, so this isn' a stripped down version of this function; it's the actual function, and makes not modifications whatsoever. On that note, quell my pedantic nature and make the argument `TreeNode const *root`. Regardless, You say, "when I assign `root = nullptr`.. " - *neither* of these code samples do that, so what are you talking about?? If you were to do that, then all your changing is the local var `root`. the caller is unaware of this, and will always be so because `root` is passed by value, not reference.

Comment: instead of return nullptr; i could do root = nullptr and it would have the same effect. so, what is so special about.                                                                    
root->left = pruneTree(root->left);
root->right = pruneTree(root->right); that allows me to directly change the root to null?

Comment: The `root = nullptr` is irrelevant. It will have the same effect as you said. This code *does* modify the tree, and the subtrees there-under. Without properly capturing those changes in the nodes themselves you're leaving your tree unchanged. The purpose is to throw out all nodes that (a) have a value of `0`, and (b) have no left or right child. Leaks notwithstanding, your code doesn't do that because you do not capture subtree changes; the proper solution does do that, and thus works. (and leaks like a sieve unless these nodes are somehow managed somewhere else as well).

Comment: thank you... i think i am beginning to understand it. correct me if im wrong: so, would it be correct to say that the earlier (incorrect) version of code stores copies of each of the left/right children but doesn't allow me to do any actual changes to them, but when I assign the return of the recursion call to root->left = prune(root->left) then now i can actually record the changes to the roots subtrees as well as the root itself?

Comment: That's exactly what that code is doing. Understand the only nodes that will ultimately be changed are those that had "pruned" the leafnodes; those nodes with '0' values and no left or right children. In that case the parent node's child pointer (such as the left member in your comment) will be set to nullptr and the link to that child leaf is lost (and as I said, probably leaked into ether, so its a bad design unless this function also deletes it). By *not* storing those changes in the members and instead capturing them in local variables you're effectively leaving your tree unchanged.

Comment: It is simple. Tree pruning would need to drop some nodes from the tree; i.e. it would need to clear some links: some `left` and `right` members would need to be set to `nullptr`. Code that never assigns anything to `left` or `right` members will not alter the links in the tree. Secondly, `root = nullptr` only alters the local variable with that name, so that doesn't affect the tree either. Remember: "call by value".